# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

I am a very new to php and mysql. And I tried to install php , mysql and apache on Ubuntu today.

Apache is fine, mysql is fine, php is fine with the installation. But!! When I tried coding :

```
<?php
       $link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:80', 'root', 'root');
       if (!$link) {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
       }
       echo 'Connected successfully';
       mysql_close($link);
?>
```

I got 500 error in Network tab of firefox. And I go to error.log and it shows `Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()`. I have googled for the whole day, got the solution that I have to uncomment `extension=php_mysql.dll` and `extension=php_mysqli.dll` and `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`.

And here is `phpinfo()` page :

```
MySQL driver for PDO    George Schlossnagle, Wez Furlong, Ilia 
MySQL   Zeev Suraski, Zak Greant, Georg Richter, Andrey Hristov
MySQLi  Zak Greant, Georg Richter, Andrey Hristov, Ulf Wendel
MySQLnd     Andrey Hristov, Ulf Wendel, Georg Richter, Johannes Schlüter
```

I really have no idea where else did I miss.

Any idea please.

Comment: Don't play pick-a-mix with mysql and mysqli functions

Comment: Did you reboot apache after enabling the extensions ?

Comment: If you're new better learn PDO it's better : http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: $con=mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname); I cant find DB name in your code. And also hope your host is " localhost " not " 127.0.0.1:80 "

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on linux first check if php-mysql in installed on it.

```
yum install php-mysql
```

Google the apt-get equivalent if you are using ubuntu.

Second check in your php.ini for mysql.so. It should not be commented.

```
extension=mysql.so
```

Comment: Please don't recommend ext/mysql to new developers; show them how to install mysqli/PDO instead.

Comment: extension=mysql.so is not found in php.ini. Did I miss installing anything?

Comment: @nothing, php and mysql are seperate services. You need a driver to connect these services. try apt-get install php5-mysql

Comment: I tried it but `Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate` error.

Comment: @Nothing, also try this apt-get install php-mysql.    Alos verify once again that you have recent version of apache2, mysql and php installed on you system.

Comment: php-mysql is already the newest version. And php version is 7.1.2 , mysql version is 14.14 and apache version is 2.4.18.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Don't mix mysql_* with mysqli_* extenstion

Note :

1) check mysql installed  properly ?

2) check mysql service started ?

3) have you restarted your apche after installing mysql.

```
        //db connection

        global $conn;

        $servername = "localhost";  //host name

        $username = "username"; //username

        $password = "password"; //password

        $mysql_database = "dbname"; //database name

       //mysqli prepared statement 

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

       mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
```

Comment: So I disable mysql extension in php.ini file. And I can use mysql in mysql shell so it means it is installed properly. And I already start mysql service and apache. And now I got 304 error instead of 500.